# HTTP Websockets client library in C++ for Windows CE/Mobile

Tags: c++, http, websocket, windows-ce, pocketpc

I am looking for a C/C++ based http/websocket library with SSL(HTTPS/wss) support on Windows CE/Mobile that uses Windows SChannel (rather than OpenSSL). I ported over the [wslay](http://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/wslay) library so that I could use it with libcurl. This is turning out to be difficult to integrate. Is anyone aware of a library that I can use on Windows CE/Mobile platforms that's not dependent on OpenSSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found POCO but that seemed to have  OpenSSL dependencies. So in turn ended up porting wslay to Windows CE and filled in the necessary callbacks with libcurl's curl_easy_send and curl_easy_receive functions for IO. Wslay doesn't have an implemented IO layer and gives the user the choice to use the appropriate IO library needed. Libcurl doss come with SChannel support that made things even more easier for using secure WebSocket over wslay.

Comment: Making my answer the best answer as I don't see any other responses.